# How to use @gitlab-ui in Vuejs3 or some library with the same design(Pajamas) or something similar

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs3, vuejs3-composition-api, gitlab-ui

I didn't find a tutorial or something similar to be able to implement @gitlab-ui in a project with Vue3, is it possible? how to make? is there any other library that uses Pajamas(https://design.gitlab.com/)? or something like bootstrap with a similar design? maybe with thunderbird ui or github? I saw something related to @vue-compat, but nothing that solved it, I couldn't get clarity on what it does and how to apply it.

I tried to install @gitlab-ui on Vue3 but I couldn't, the following is returned to me

`npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @gitlab/ui@64.10.1
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.3.4
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^3.2.25" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@4.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!     dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^4.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@vue/server-renderer)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.6.10" from @gitlab/ui@64.10.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@gitlab/ui
npm ERR!   @gitlab/ui@"^64.10.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.7.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^2.6.10" from @gitlab/ui@64.10.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@gitlab/ui
npm ERR!     @gitlab/ui@"^64.10.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/rafael/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rafael/.npm/_logs/2023-08-02T20_32_48_662Z-debug-0.log
`